# Interfaz gráfica para abrir y leer varios archivos ".txt"

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código para abrir un archivo ".txt" de forma gráfica. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para poder abrir "n" número de archivos ".txt"? Algo como esto:

```
FileReader Entrada[] = {new FileReader("archivo1.txt"), 
                new FileReader("archivo2.txt"),new FileReader("archivo3.txt")};
```

```
        JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser(ruta_archivo);
        //Indicamos que podemos seleccionar varios ficheros
        j.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        FileNameExtensionFilter fi = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt", "txt");

        j.setFileFilter(fi);
        int se = j.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (se == 0) {
            ruta_archivo = j.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            abrir_pdf(ruta_archivo);


        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No selecciono ningun archivo");
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que deseas?¿El código no te funciona?¿Tienes alguna duda? Debes ser claro en lo que estás buscando, para que los demás te puedan ayudar.

Comment: si funciona pero quiero saber si puedo leer varios txt de forma grafica